# Splice a quosure and format into a list of strings

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

The `by` argument in `dplyr::left_join` (and friends) expects a list of strings. My code already defines the variables of interest as a list of quosures so I want to avoid writing the list down a second time by converting the list of quosures to a list of strings.

I went hunting around the `rlang` docs but did not find an existing solution. The `quo_expr` family of functions can splice and convert quosures to a single string but they do not produce a list of strings:

```
library(rlang)

# this works
sepal_length <- quo(Sepal.Length)
quo_text(sepal_length)

# this doesnt
sepaldims <- quos(Species, Sepal.Length)
quo_text(sepaldims)
```

Here's an example where this would be useful:

```
library(dplyr)

# group_by accepts a list of quosures
sepaldims <- quos(Species, Sepal.Length)
iris_sepal <- iris %>%
  group_by(!!!sepaldims) %>%
  summarize(sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width), petal_width = mean(Petal.Width))    
petaldims <- quos(!!!sepaldims, Petal.Length)
iris_petal <- iris %>%
  group_by(!!!petaldims) %>%
  summarize(sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width), petal_width = mean(Petal.Width))

# but left join expects a list of strings
iris_merge <- left_join(iris_sepal, iris_petal, by = c("Species", "Sepal.Length"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I came up with applies `quo_text` to the list:

```
quos_text <- function(qs) {
  unlist(lapply(seq_along(qs), function(i) quo_text(qs[[i]])))
}
```

Now we can handle lists of quosures:

```
sepaldims <- quos(Species, Sepal.Length)
petaldims <- quos(!!!sepaldims, Petal.Length)

quos_text(sepaldims)
quos_text(petaldims)
quos_text(quos(!!!sepaldims, Petal.Width))
```

And `left_join` is satisfied:

```
# these two are equivalent
iris_merge <- left_join(iris_sepal, iris_petal, by = c("Species", "Sepal.Length"))
iris_merge2 <- left_join(iris_sepal, iris_petal, by = quos_text(sepaldims))
```

@Marius has pointed out that there is a simpler form we can use:

```
sapply(qs, quo_text)
```

This is short enough I will probably use it inline rather than as a custom function.

Comment: I think your `quos_text` function can be simplified to `sapply(qs, quo_text)`.